# OBIEE 12c invoke java method. Can not find the EJB and method

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic12c, oracle12c, obiee

I am working with OBIEE 12c. I am trying to call a java method to save the report into the local file system with an agent. I followed the steps for 11g version at this link http://docslide.us/documents/how-to-create-and-invoke-enterpise-java-beans-ejb-using-the-action-framework.html .I used exactly the same application names, project names, and configurations.After everything I go to OBI and click on the invoke a java method link. This is what I am getting. There is no method named "ArchiveReport". Does anyone know what might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out there was an issue with my mappedName for the EJB class.

I found a working example compared everything, found out the mappedName for the EJB class has to be ejb/xxxx. After changing this and regenerated the ear file. I am able to see my EJB now.

Comment: Could you tell me where's the config file located?

Comment: Sorry, I did not say it clearly. I am using annotations for this EJB and the mappedName is the annotation right above the EJB's class name. If you have any other problems please let me know. Maybe I can help.